# Simulation of avalanches with hexagonal cells

Tags: python, matplotlib, hex, cellular-automata

My request is perhaps a bit complicated but I try.

I'm writing a program that simulates the behavior of an avalanche through a cellular automaton. It is simulated by a matrix whose cells are hexagonal.

the problem I'm trying to solve is the following:
I would like to have a graphical representation of these hexagons but I can not find any other way except through hexbin, but being a histogram it does not help me much. Is there a way to represent this matrix with hexagons?

Thank u all

Comment: I don't know much about cellular automata, however: how does the matrix which you want to visualize look like? How are indices represented?

Comment: What should be visualized in every cell - a single color, just black or white?

Comment: Each cell in the matrix is ​​represented by several parameters, some of which change at each iteration, such as the density of the snow. Initially I am trying to have a hexagonal view of a simpler matrix in which the values ​​are random. The use of hexbin is a bit complicated to apply to my case being a histogram and requiring as x and y two 1d arrays.
@SpghttCd